# Show image in TextView from HTML string

Tags: java, android, textview

Hi I parsing XML with jsoup and I can show string html to TextView.
I use spannable to sting, It's Work but no show Image, How to fix?

```
Spannable storySpan
storySpan = new SpannableString("<p><strong>Text</strong>TextText</p><p>Text2</p><p><img src="http://web.com/link-img.jpg"></p><p>Text2</p>");

articletext.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.valueOf(storySpan)), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

**Output Above Code**

**Text** - TextText

Text2

[image]

Text3

How to show image ?
Thanks.